# I want make java Jtree of Selected file from JFileChooser in my Project

Tags: java, swing, jtree, filetree

**This is my TreeModel Class**

```
    BusinessLayer;

    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

    /**
     *
     * @author attam
     */
    public class FileTreeModel implements TreeModel
    {
        // Attributes
        private File root;

        /**
         *  Constructor initializes the root of TreeModel
         * @param root directory
         */
        public FileTreeModel(File root)
        {
            this.root = root;
        }

        /**
         *  Returns root of the TreeModel i.e. JTree
         * @return root
         */
        public Object getRoot()
        {
            return root;
        }

        /**
         * Check if given node is root or not
         * @param node the node to be checked
         * @return true if it is root else false
         */
        public boolean isLeaf(Object node)
        {
            return ((File)node).isFile();
        }

        /**
         * Returns number of child nodes in JTree
         * @param parent Parent node
         * @return no of child nodes
         */
        public int getChildCount(Object parent)
        {
            String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
            if (children == null) return 0;
            return children.length;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the child node by its index
         * @param parent Parent Node
         * @param index  Index of child node
         * @return child node
         */
        public Object getChild(Object parent, int index)
        {
            String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
            if ((children == null) || (index >= children.length))
                return null;
            return new File((File) parent, children[index]);
        }

        /**
         * Return index of child node
         * @param parent Parent of child
         * @param child  child node
         * @return index of child node
         */
        public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child)
        {
            String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
            if (children == null)
                return -1;
            String childname = ((File)child).getName();
            for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
            {
                if (childname.equals(children[i]))
                    return i;
            }
                return -1;

        }
        @Override
        public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newvalue) {}

        @Override
        public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}

        @Override
        public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}

    }
```

this is TreeModel class where i declear tree functinality

**this is the class from where the filechooser function is called**

```
    package BusinessLayer;

    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * @author Mohsin Atta
     * @Reg # 3258-BSSE/F16
     */

    public class FileInformation {
        public static JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        public static List<File> allFiles;
        public static String folderName;




        public static File getAllFiles() {
             List<File> fileList=new ArrayList<>();

            // JButton open = new JButton();
            if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File files[] = fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles();
                fileList= Arrays.asList(files);
                allFiles=fileList;
                return fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory();
            }
            return null;

        }

        public static List<File> getJavaFiles() {
            List<File> fileList=new ArrayList<>();
            for(File file:allFiles)
            {
                if(file.getName().endsWith(".java"))
                {
                    fileList.add(file);
                    ClassAndMethodExtractor obj = new `ClassAndMethodExtractor(file);`
                    obj.getPublicClass();
                    obj.getPublicMethods();
                }

            }
            return fileList;
        }
    }
```

**in above file in getAllFiles function**

**and this is the function where I set the tree but not dispalyed the tree**

```
    public static void setFileList(File file) throws IOException 
    {
        String setFolder;
       // setFolder = folder+" Accessed";
        if (file != null) 
        {
            TreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(file);
            tree.setModel(model);
                //allFilesArea.append(file.getCanonicalPath());
                //allFilesArea.append("\n");
        }
    }
```

i face the problem that is i declare the tree and also use it according to method but still it doesn't show the tree and also it doesn't give any error.. so kindly give the solution or any other alternative to make tree of File path

Comment: 1) See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for use of good icons in a tree. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: its difficult to understand for me as i'm beginner i want to Make Jtree of a File Path and show it on JtextArea...

Comment: Well good luck with that. Until you can post an MCVE /SSCCE of your attempt and form a (specific) question to go with it. I don't see what more I can do.

Comment: thanks for your time